# @SessionScoped throws Exception. (LifecycleException - "UserSession is annotated with an invalid scope")

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

Until now i used the JSF implemented (but deprecated) ManagedBeans for my webapplication.

After i changed it to CDI-beans . (javax.enterprise.context.*)

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
@Named
public class UserSession implements Serializable, HttpSessionListener
{
//.....
}
```

I got following Exceptions:

> ```
> ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
> ```
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class
>   **xbu.gbcp.bean.session.UserSession is annotated with an invalid scope**
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5864)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
>         at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>         at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>         at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>         at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bean implements `HttpSessionListener` and declaring CDI scopes for listeners, servlets or filters is not allowed. You need to refactor and extract the session listener related logic into a separate class.